# When performing a migration, how do you handle a new column needing a value but not being able to provide one for the migration?

Tags: postgresql, migration, best-practices

I'm adding a timezone column to a table; the value cannot be NULL. However, I can only alter the table if I add a default value, but there isn't a way to determine that value before the migration.

How does something like this get handled?

**Example**:

Current:

| id | street | zip_code | ..etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | data | zip | ... |

Migration to do this:

| id | street | zip_code | ..etc | timezone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | data | zip | ... | America/Los_Angeles |

Answer (score 0):

One way is to

1. Define **timezone** as nulllable in the destination.
2. Migrate the data
3. Fill in all values for it
4. Make it non-null